# Get_user running at kernel mode returns error

Tags: linux-kernel

I have a problem with get_user() macro. What I did is as follows:

I run the following program

```
int main() 
{ 
    int a = 20; 
    printf("address of a: %p", &a); 
    sleep(200); 
    return 0; 
}
```

When the program runs, it outputs the address of a, say, 0xbff91914.

Then I pass this address to a module running in Kernel Mode that retrieves the contents at this address (at the time when I did this, I also made sure the process didn't terminate, because I put it to sleep for 200 seconds... ):

The address is firstly sent as a string, and I cast them into pointer type.

```
int * ptr = (int*)simple_strtol(buffer, NULL,16); 
printk("address: %p",ptr); // I use this line to make sure the cast is correct. When running, it outputs bff91914, as expected. 
int val = 0; 
int res; 
res= get_user(val, (int*) ptr);
```

However, res is always not 0, meaning that get_user returns error. I am wondering what is the problem....

Thank you!!

-- Fangkai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `get_user` must be made in the context of the user process.

Since you write "I also made sure the process didn't terminate, because I put it to sleep for 200 seconds..." I have a feeling you are not abiding by that rule.  For the call to get_user to be in the context of the user process, you would have had to make a system call from that process and there would not have been a need to sleep the process.

So, you need to have your user process make a system call (an `ioctl` would be fine) and from that system call make the call to `get_user`.

Comment: Thank you, now I know what is the problem. But in my project, I am developing a virtual device driver such that user can read any process's memory contents by specifying its pid and virtual address. Therefore, a device /dev/gh is registered, and the user try to do something like: echo -n targetpid>/dev/gh & echo -n addr>/dev/gh Therefore, the target process can't be modified. The device driver will retrieve the value by pid and virtual address and return it to user. I don't know how to solve this problem with get_user under my scenario. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

That is probably because you're trying to get value from a **different** user space. That address you got is from your simple program's address space, while you're probably using **another** program for passing the value to the module, aren't you?

Comment: Well, I tried not to pass the address to module from any other program. What I do now is: after output the address of the variable, I change the code of the module, set the ptr to the address, and recompile, reload the module again. I make sure that the simple program is still running. However, get_user still returns error...

Comment: Yes, I understand what you meant... when I refer user space, the current->pid is pointing to another process, therefore it is in a different context... How to fix this problem?

Comment: You have to arrange things so that you can do the `get_user()` when `current` is the target process - for example, after sleeping you could have your target process read a file in `/proc` created by your module, and do the `get_user` in the proc file's read routine.

Comment: Yes. The point is, your process must *somehow* call into your module. Then your module's code will be executed in that process's context. Reading a file created by the module would be one of ways to do it.